# Reusing Fragments - Is it bad idea? Is it good idea? And is it possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

Clearly Android is not [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) oriented. Otherwise [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)(Model), [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)(View), and [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)(controller) would not be in the same [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)(Activity).

It hearts the most while working with fragments, their life cycle is bounded in to the activity they hosted by. for instance: I am working with [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), one of it's tabs, which is a fragment, is also a popup in same activity. It's a complicated view, it has a lot of models and controllers(Mixed friends list from both Facebook and Google+, bounded by my application filter). I do not wan't to recreate this view. I want some magic way that will make it a tab and then a popup and then a screen in other scenarios.

So should I keep instance of the same fragment and push it over my app, while changing the views? Or should I only keep the view instance? Or should I forget **MVC** and push it all into [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)() and try to remember which friend come before which?

What Android suggest? And what do you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

Reusing fragments is a really good idea if made wisely, the most advantage you get is on multi-device applications.

For example, an application for tablets can be delivered to phones.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design) you can have "headless" fragments that dont die with activities...

Comment: They have a different meaning for "reusing". I am spiking about keeping the same fragment instance, and pushing it to tab and to popup, some time after that. In the article they speak about reusing the same fragment in different activities and devices(reusing the class, not the instance)

Comment: Well i think your approach would lead to memory leaks, why not to use services for providing data and "reuse" fragments the intended way?. That is reusing, you are talking about "persisting" fragments, it's different.

Comment: No, in both cases it the same term: Reuse. There is no such thing in computer since as "persisting"

Comment: Also where did you read about "headless fragments that dont die with activities"? I didn't found it.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52068/discussion-between-frederic-yesid-pena-sanchez-and-ilya-gazman)